# Memory leak caused by ScrollView (ScrollInfo) Action on RadListBox

Tags: wpf

[enter image description here][1]I add an item to the RadListBox and always update it to record the operation status of the program in real time

Adding items to the listbox is not a problem, but memory leaks have occurred since i added the syntax to change the SelectedItem.

According to the diagnostic tool, there is an accumulation of memory of the "Action" object and the "scrollInfo" type of wpf, but I don't know exactly what this is

This is not a problem that occurs faster than the processing speed of the task

This type of memory leak does not occur if use Winform ListBox instead of wpf, or do not update SelectedItem.(even using Wpf)

Occurs only in Visible ListBox during TAB.

```
    delegate void DInsertList(RadListBox nlistbox, string str);
    public static void InsertList(RadListBox nlistbox, string str)
    {
        if (nlistbox.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
        {
            if (str != null)
            {
                if (nlistbox.Items.Count > 100)
                {
                  nlistbox.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                
                nlistbox.Items.Add(str);
         //       nlistbox.SelectedIndex = (int )(nlistbox.Items.Count - 1);
                nlistbox.SelectedItem = nlistbox.Items[(int)(nlistbox.Items.Count - 1)];
            }
        }
        else
        {

            DInsertList call = new DInsertList(InsertList);
            nlistbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(call, nlistbox, str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know about radlist ox, but the Wpf listbox is designed tso it can virtualise and re use listbox items. I suggest you consider mvvm and bind an observablecollection of data you want to present. Bind is selected and as an item moves in the view it's the same row viewmodel so you're only relying on binding and weak reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a memory leak. It's just memory allocation. It's a leak if the garbage collector won't be able to free the allocated memory.
What you witness is the inefficiency of removing visible item containers from the virtualizing `ListBox` (or `RadListBox` which extends the WPF `ListBox`), escalated by the fact that you have unknowingly disabled UI virtualization.

The `ListBox` uses UI virtualization. This feature allows that only the visible item containers are created and loaded (realized).
Without UI virtualization enabled, all item containers would be created immediately at once.

Now, when you remove an item from a collection at an index that is not the last, then this operation results in reordering of the items. For example, removing the first item will impact the complete collection as it changes the index of every item.

If this change affects the realized item container, then the `ListBox` is forced to recreate the view, which results in the creation of new item container instances (e.g. `ListBoxItem`) and a complete pass of the layout engine to render the new containers.
The memory profiler reflects this by showing an increase in allocated memory (for the new containers).
The `IScrollInfo` is implemented by the underlying `VirtualizingStackPanel` of the `ListBox` and controls the actual realization of item containers based on the current scroll position. Of course, this type is involved when recreating the view as it actually decides what is visible and what is not.

Unless your erroneous item container handling results in keeping the references alive, the garbage collector will free the memory of the old item containers after a while.

However, when UI virtualization is enabled, the overall performance impact of removing/replacing visible items is quite low.

You can further reduce the impact by configuring the `ListBox` to recycle its containers. This way the item containers are not recreated each time and the `ListBox` can reuse them:

```xml
<ListBox VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

Using container recycling can introduce issues if the containers have an individual state.

### Fixing your issues

From your posted code I can tell that you are adding `ListBoxItems` explicitly (because modifying the `ListBox` via the `Items` property would otherwise result in an exception).
By not using the `ItemsSource` property to populate the `ListBox` you will silently disable the previously described UI virtualization feature.

Under these circumstances, the performance impact of removing an item is extremely high as this operation forces the `ListBox` to throw away *all* item containers instead of only the visible ones.
The spike in memory usage will skyrocket and the UI can feel sluggish or even freeze (all depends on the number of items - the more items, the more the impact).

For this reason, you must always modify an `ItemsControl` via a source collection of type `ObservableCollection`.

You can further improve your posted code by removing redundancies and using proper APIs.

The suggested fixes look as follows:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> Values
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ValuesProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValuesProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Values", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public string SelectedValue
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedValue",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize with "A" to "Z"
    IEnumerable<string> textValues = Enumerable.Range(65, 26).Select(value => new string(new[] { (char)value }));
    this.Values = new ObservableCollection<string>(textValues);
  }

  // Consider making this an instance method. 
  // Global class methods usually lead to bad design.
  public static void InsertList(string str)
  {   
    // Alternative use Application.Current.Dispatcher 
    // if you are not in the scope of a DispatcherObject
    if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
      if (str != null)
      {
        if (this.Values.Count > 100)
        {
          this.Values.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        // Adding an item automatically inserts it at the end...
        this.Values.Add(str);

        // ...that's why we can avoid looking up the last item...
        //nlistbox.SelectedItem = nlistbox.Items[(int)(nlistbox.Items.Count - 1)];
   
        // ...and simply use the reference of the currently added item 'str'
        this.SelectedValue = str;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => InsertList(str));
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWIndow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Name="Root">

  <!-- 
       Now that the list is populated using the ItemsSource, 
       UI virtualization is enabled, which will significantly improve 
       the performance of the ListBox (in terms of memory and rendering speed).
       Configuring the control to recycle item containers will 
       further improve the performance.
  -->
  <RadListBox VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Values}"
              SelectedItem="{Bidning ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedItem}" />
</Window>
```